# Can't get <ul> to display in center

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display my list in the center of the page, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.
Help would be much appreciated!
http://jsfiddle.net/eg0ayup8/

```
<div class="tracks">  
<ul>
  <li>The Genesis</li>
  <li>NY State of Mind</li>
  <li>Life's a Bitch</li>
  <li>The World Is Yours</li>
  <li>Halftime</li>
  <li>Memory Lane (Sittin' in da Park)</li>
  <li>One Love</li>
  <li>One Time 4 Your Mind</li>
  <li>Represent</li>
  <li>It Ain't Hard To Tell</li>
</ul>
```

```
.tracks ul {
display: inline-block;
float: none;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #666;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `ul` is an inline-block element you can center with this on the parent, try with:

```
.tracks {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Updated **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eg0ayup8/1/)**

Answer (score 4):

```
.tracks ul {
    margin : auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eg0ayup8/2/

Comment: You may need to note the obligatory `width` property in order to get the `margin:auto` works